# Different Combinations (15 from 60 numbers)

Tags: combinations

I can choose 15 from 60 numbers (1 to 60), without any repetition.

e.g.:
1-5-10-15-20-25-30-35-40-45-50-55-57-58-59

How many different combinations can I choose?

Comment: What did you try?  What do you know so far about problems like these?

Comment: @CPM I know that if I can choose 6 elements, I will have 50.063.860 different combinations. But I don't know how to calculate with 15 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So based on your comment above, I am assuming you know about combinations at least a bit.  If there are $60$ people (think about them being labeled from 1 to 60) and you are picking a collection of $6$ to form a group, you apparently know that the answer is $\binom{60}{6}=50063860$.  If you are doing the same thing with picking a collection of 15 numbers i.e. people, you just need to compute 
$\binom{60}{15}$.

$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$  Can you take it from here?